# What triggers Resharper's warning: "possible null assignment to non-nullable entity"?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've got this method, which gives Resharper warning:

```
private static void Example(Type type,object sourceOfString)
{
    string str = sourceOfString.ToString();
    var field = type.GetField(str); //possible null assignment to non-nullable entity
}
```

My understanding was that the warning was triggered by a `[NotNull]` attribute on the parameter of `GetField`, so I made some code to test that:

```
private static void Example(Type type,object sourceOfString)
{
    string str = sourceOfString.ToString();
    var field = type.GetField(str); //possible null assignment to non-nullable entity
    Foo(str); //No warning
    Bar(str); //No warning
}

private static void Foo(string value) {}

private static void Bar([NotNull]string value) {}
```

But `Bar` does not trigger the warning, so it can't be the `[NotNull]` parameter. What makes things even weirder is that the warning goes away when the string is passed as a parameter:

```
private static void Example2(Type type,object sourceOfString)
{
    Example(type, sourceOfString.ToString());//No warning
}

private static void Example(Type type,string str)
{
    var field = type.GetField(str);//No warning
}
```

What causes the warning to appear or not appear?

Comment: Maybe resharper just assume that in `object` someone can override 'ToString' to return null and by default assume that it is possible. Anyway, you can report that case on this post [Resharper page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/AssignNullToNotNullAttribute.html).

Comment: @HenrykBudzinski I understand that, but then why doesn't `Bar` give the same warning?

Comment: I wrote it incorrectly in the message above. What I meant is that all classes inherit from `object`, and you can override the `ToString()` method and return `null`. So it is always possible for the `ToString(`" of an object to return null. That's why he inserts the warning.
The string type is a sealed class and you cannot inherit and override the `ToString()` method. The default `ToString()` never return null.